# Which schema has done insert, update or delete

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

actually I'm creating a before insert or update or delete trigger which will look on a table `IMP_CUSTOMER` and log the dataset which was updated, inserted or deleted into a table `LOG_IMP_CUSTOMER`. Everything work's fine but I just missing one point:

The data in the table can be changed by different database user and I'm trying to get the user which has done the change on the table to log that also into my log table.

This is my trigger until now:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_LOG_IMP_CUSTOMER
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON IMP_CUSTOMER
REFERENCING OLD AS old_buffer NEW AS new_buffer FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
log_date TIMESTAMP;
sql_type VARCHAR(1);
log_user VARCHAR(10);
BEGIN
-- set log_date
log_date := SYSDATE;

-- set sql_type
IF INSERTING THEN sql_type := 'I';
END IF;
IF UPDATING THEN sql_type := 'U';
END IF;
IF DELETING THEN sql_type := 'D';
END IF;

-- set log_user
log_user := 'USER'; -- hardcoded for test

-- log update and delete
IF UPDATING OR DELETING THEN
    INSERT INTO LOG_IMP_CUSTOMER VALUES (:old_buffer.CIF_ID,:old_buffer.PHONE_NUMBER,:old_buffer.PHONE_AREACODE,SEQ_LOG_IMP_CUSTOMER.nextval,log_date,sql_type,log_user);
END IF;

-- log insert
IF INSERTING THEN
    INSERT INTO LOG_IMP_CUSTOMER VALUES
    (:new_buffer.CIF_ID,:new_buffer.PHONE_NUMBER,:new_buffer.PHONE_AREACODE,SEQ_LOG_IMP_CUSTOMER.nextval,log_date,sql_type,log_user);
END IF;
END;
/
```

I just searching for any way to set `log_user` to the user which has done the change.

Some good ideas?

Thanks and regards,
David

Comment: Just remove the quotes: `log_user := USER;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can edit like below.

```
log_user := sys_context('USERENV','SESSION_USER');
```